# Jensen's inequality of Indicator function

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

Is there any way to get rid of the $$F_T$$ in this formula? where U>T>t>0

$$ \begin{aligned} & \mathbb E[(\mathbb E[1_{{s_U}>K}|F_T])^n|F_t]\\
\end{aligned}$$

The best approach I have at the moment is to use the Jensen inequality and the tower property, to get a lower bond if n>1
$$ \begin{aligned} & \mathbb E[ (\mathbb E[1_{{s_U}>K}|F_T])^n|F_t]\\
& >=(\mathbb E[\mathbb E[1_{{s_U}<K}|F_T]|F_t])^n\\
& =(\mathbb E[1_{{s_U}>K}|F_t])^n
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you can just apply the tower property without using jensens:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1}_{S_U > K} | F_T \right]^n | F_t \right] = \mathbb{E}[(\mathbb{1}_{S_U > K})^n | F_t].$$

Comment: do you know why?

Comment: Sorry my statement was wrong. If we assume $F_T = F_t = \{ \emptyset, \Omega\}, A = \{S_U > K\}$, then 
$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A^n | F_t] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}^n_A] = P(A)$$
and 
$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A|F_T]^n|F_t] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_A]^n] = P(A)^n.$$

sry for my stupid mistake :/